# Error with Character Replacement VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba

Consider the following VBA Function:

```
Sub RemoveLetters()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim str As String: str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 "
    Dim ltr As String

    For i = 1 To 37

        ltr = Mid(str, i, 1)

        Sheet9.Range("A2:A1800").Replace _
            What:=ltr, Replacement:="", MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This function gets rid of all letter and number characters in a given string.  However, the error I encounter is that whenever a string begins with a non-letter, non-number string it fails to execute on that string and does not execute on any further strings.  That is, running into such a string stops the execution.  Is there an obvious reason why this is happening?  How might I modify this code to fix it?

Comment: Just tried it with `$asd` and it worked. What are examples of these strings that "begins with a non-letter, non-number"?

Comment: For example, @gmail.com would halt the macro. It is the only thing I can think of that is causing a problem as in every case this fails @ seems to pop up at the start.

Comment: Just tested with `bk201@gmail.com`. The macro left `'@.` on my cell, which should be correct, as `@` functions the same way as `=`, `-`, etc in that they can start formulas, so Excel forces them to string format by adding `'`. (Try `@SUM`. It's the same as `=SUM`.) I don't see why this should throw an error, really, on your end. What happens if you add `On Error Resume Next` before the `For i=...` line?

Comment: @BK201 Same error it seems.  Did you try a case where @ is the first character in a cell?  It does seem to work when I add a space in front of @ string cells.  Is there a way to prevent Excel reading @ in the same way as =?  I tried changing to text format without success.

Comment: As I said, it's pretty impossible to start a cell in Excel with `@` as it reads as a formula. Check the formula bar while this cell on your end is highlighted. What does it show? Just `@string` or `'@string`? I bet it starts with `'`. That will stop the macro, based on my tests.

Comment: @BK201 It just shows @ string, strangely.  It may be because the values were copied into the cells from a text file.

Comment: Fair enough. Posting an alternative. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matching patterns, the best option is `regular expressions` or more commonly known as `regex`. By defining a set pattern to follow, you can extract or replace almost anything you want.

To replace all non-number and non-letter characters as well as spaces, a small function like the following works:

```
Function NoNormalChar(StrTarget As String) As String
    Dim oRegEx As Object
    Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With oRegEx
        .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+"
        .Global = True
        NoNormalChar = .Replace(StrTarget, "")
    End With
End Function
```

Calling it inside a sub is simple enough:

```
Sub RemoveLetters()
    Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Rng = Sheet9.Range("A2:A1800")
    For Each Cell In Rng
        Cell.Value = NoNormalChar(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Copy and paste both to a single module. Run on a back-up copy and let us know of the results.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks!  If you happen to come up with another idea as to why @ was giving me an issue before please do let me know.

Comment: As a follow up, would it be possible for you to explain how the function you defined works?  I am not sure I fully understand that part, though it does work wonderfully.

Comment: Gladly. Basically, regular expressions works on a pattern. The learning curve is ***very steep***, since it mainly relies on your creativity after learning it and it's very easy to create a bad pattern. As said over and over, you need a pattern. The pattern above is `[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+`. The way it's read is: `all characters from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and spaces (\s), in any grouping ([]) and of an indeterminate length (+)`. When the pattern is locked in, We call on `.Replace` to "hit" every character that fits the pattern and replace them with `""`. Say you want to remove `*` as well...

Comment: ... It's as easy as changing the pattern to `[a-zA-Z0-9\s\*]`. The backslash escapes the `*` as `*` is a special character in `RegEx`. I highly suggest checking out tutorials online. There's a lot. My personal favorite has to be http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/. Check out the free HTML version. :)